# Removing Title from Full Contact Name

Tags: c#

I'm writing a little function to remove common titles from a full contact name field. This is what I have so far:

```
string[] CommonTitles = new string[] { "MR ", "MRS ", "MS ", "MISS ", "DR ", "HERR ", "MONSIEUR ", "HR ", "FRAU ", "A V M ", "ADMIRAAL ", 
                "ADMIRAL ", "ALDERMAN ", "ALHAJI ", "AMBASSADOR ", "BARON ", "BARONES ", "BRIG ", "BRIGADIER ", "BROTHER ", "CANON ", "CAPT ", "CAPTAIN ", 
                "CARDINAL ", "CDR ", "CHIEF ", "CIK ", "CMDR ", "COL ", "COLONEL ", "COMMANDANT ", "COMMANDER ", "COMMISSIONER ", "COMMODORE ", "COMTE ", 
                "COMTESSA ", "CONGRESSMAN ", "CONSEILLER ", "CONSUL ", "CONTE ", "CONTESSA ", "CORPORAL ", "COUNCILLOR ", "COUNT ", "COUNTESS ", "AIR CDRE ", 
                "AIR COMMODORE ", "AIR MARSHAL ", "AIR VICE MARSHAL ", "BRIG GEN ", "BRIG GENERAL ", "BRIGADIER GENERAL ", "CROWN PRINCE ", "CROWN PRINCESS ", 
                "DAME ", "DATIN ", "DATO ", "DATUK ", "DATUK SERI ", "DEACON ", "DEACONESS ", "DEAN ", "DHR ", "DIPL ING ", "DOCTOR ", "DOTT ", "DOTT SA ", 
                "DR ", "DR ING ", "DRA ", "DRS ", "EMBAJADOR ", "EMBAJADORA ", "EN ", "ENCIK ", "ENG ", "EUR ING ", "EXMA SRA ", "EXMO SR ", "F O ", 
                "FATHER ", "FIRST LIEUTIENT ", "FIRST OFFICER ", "FLT LIEUT ", "FLYING OFFICER ", "FR ", "FRAU ", "FRAULEIN ", "FRU ", "GEN ", "GENERAAL ", 
                "GENERAL ", "GOVERNOR ", "GRAAF ", "GRAVIN ", "GROUP CAPTAIN ", "GRP CAPT ", "H E DR ", "H H ", "H M ", "H R H ", "HAJAH ", "HAJI ", 
                "HAJIM ", "HER HIGHNESS ", "HER MAJESTY ", "HERR ", "HIGH CHIEF ", "HIS HIGHNESS ", "HIS HOLINESS ", "HIS MAJESTY ", "HON ", "HR ", 
                "HRA ", "ING ", "IR ", "JONKHEER ", "JUDGE ", "JUSTICE ", "KHUN YING ", "KOLONEL ", "LADY ", "LCDA ", "LIC ", "LIEUT ", "LIEUT CDR ", 
                "LIEUT COL ", "LIEUT GEN ", "LORD ", "MADAME ", "MADEMOISELLE ", "MAJ GEN ", "MAJOR ", "MASTER ", "MEVROUW ", "MISS ", "MLLE ", "MME ", 
                "MONSIEUR ", "MONSIGNOR ", "MSTR ", "NTI ", "PASTOR ", "PRESIDENT ", "PRINCE ", "PRINCESS ", "PRINCESSE ", "PRINSES ", "PROF ", 
                "PROF DR ", "PROF SIR ", "PROFESSOR ", "PUAN ", "PUAN SRI ", "RABBI ", "REAR ADMIRAL ", "REV ", "REV CANON ", "REV DR ", "REV MOTHER ", 
                "REVEREND ", "RVA ", "SENATOR ", "SERGEANT ", "SHEIKH ", "SHEIKHA ", "SIG ", "SIG NA ", "SIG RA ", "SIR ", "SISTER ", "SQN LDR ", "SR ", 
                "SR D ", "SRA ", "SRTA ", "SULTAN ", "TAN SRI ", "TAN SRI DATO ", "TENGKU ", "TEUKU ", "THAN PUYING ", "THE HON DR ", "THE HON JUSTICE ", 
                "THE HON MISS ", "THE HON MR ", "THE HON MRS ", "THE HON MS ", "THE HON SIR ", "THE VERY REV ", "TOH PUAN ", "TUN ", "VICE ADMIRAL ", 
                "VISCOUNT ", "VISCOUNTESS ", "WG CDR " };



            string returnName = textBox1.Text.ToUpper();

            foreach (string title in CommonTitles)
            {
                returnName = returnName.Replace(title, "");
            }

            MessageBox.Show(returnName);
```

However, I have just tried to test this with the following input: **KHUN YING Abu Dina Mr MRS TOH MAJOR** But I get this back: KHUN YABU DINA TOH MAJOR

Is there something better than using a REPLACE function?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The reason it does not replace MAJOR is your common titles have spaces next to each title, and MAJOR in your example does not have one (since it is the last word).  This is a pretty ugly function and prone to error.

Comment: Run it in the debugger with a breakpoint on the replace - I've bet you've got two or more titles that are colliding

Comment: IMO this is not a way of removing titles. What if there is a dot after Mr and Mrs like `"Mr. Toh Major"`, then it will be become `". Toh Major`?

Comment: Use a regex with word boundary replacement instead of including spaces in your filter strings.

Comment: @ Nikhil Agrawal, I perform other data cleaning routines on the FullContactName field such removing dots etc... so this shouldn't cause an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions. First you have to remove the trailing space from all your titles. Then you can use the anchor `\b` to match on a word boundary. To avoid extra spaces you also need to match spaces either in front or after the title (I do it after by using `\s*`). You might still have a trailing space so you also need to `Trim()` the string:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\b(" + string.Join("|", CommonTitles) + @")\b\s*");
var result = regex.Replace("KHUN YING ABU DINA MR MRS TOH MAJOR", String.Empty).Trim();
```

This results in:

```
ABU DINA TOH
```

You can also let the regular expression handle the case problem to avoid converting everything to upper case. Simply use the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`:

```
var regex = new Regex(
  @"\b(" + string.Join("|", CommonTitles) + @")\b\s*",
  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
var result = regex.Replace("Khun Ying Abu Dina Mr Mrs Toh Major", String.Empty).Trim();
```

Now the result is:

```
Abu Dina Toh
```